# How to Transpose rows into columns in SQLite or flutter moor?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, transpose, flutter-moor

How can I convert rows into columns.

[initial structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2lpd.png)

Needed Output:

```
OrderId -> Product1 -> QuantityOfProduct1 -> ... ProductN -> QuantityOfProductN -> totalAmount -> Date
```

Please help me to achieve this.
sorry for improper questioning.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the JSON you can getting?

Comment: I ran this query on sqlite browser and the output of that query is included in question as an image